# Why React re-renders a component even when changed prop or state has no relation to JSX?

Tags: reactjs

Why does React re-renders a component when its prop or state changes even though the changed prop or state has no relation to the returned JSX?

I read about [React Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) from the official documentation. It explains the diffing mechanism but not the need for re-rendering a component when the state has no visual impact on Virtual DOM tree.

Consider the trivial dummy code given below where `myState` is a state of the `App` component and it has no relation to the returned JSX but still if `myState` gets updated (which happens inside the `buttonClickHandler`, React re-renders the `App` component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  console.log("[App] rendered");

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);

  const buttonClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("Button clicked!");
    setMyState((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return <button onClick={buttonClickHandler}>Click Me</button>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because React can't possibly know whether a state or prop change has an effect on the JSX before you return it.

Even if a component is rerendered, it doesn't mean it's re-reconciled into the real DOM (and indeed, if there are no changes, the DOM is left untouched).

If a function component's render is computationally heavy, you can use e.g. `useMemo` to memoize those heavy computations.